# What is the difference in defining a variable in .h file's interface() method alone without synthesizing it?

Tags: objective-c, header, scope, getter-setter, synthesis

I define a variable in .h file's interface method like this...

```
@interface ......{
  int a;
}
```

Then i use it in .m file, it works fine....

Also i modified the code as

```
@interface ......{
  int a;
}
@property(nonatomic) int a;
```

in .h file, and in .m file i set the int value as

```
@synthesize a;
```

Now also it works fine...

What is the different between both cases?

Comment: What language/platform is this?

Comment: This is objective-C.  Retagging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference in defining a variable in .h file's interface() method alone without synthesizing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643692/what-is-the-difference-in-defining-a-variable-in-h-files-interface-method-alo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring your 'a' property you are allowing for the int to be stored in your class and you can access it from within your class - but *only* within your class. If you want it to be a property that is accessible by other objects (a public property) then you need getter and setter methods.

By declaring it as a `@property` in your `.h` and using `@synthesize` in your `.m`, you are automatically creating two methods:

```
[myObject a]; // your getter
[myObject setA:50]; // your setter
```

One thing to keep in mind here is that it is often a very good idea to use sythesised properties even within your class because they will take care of your memory management. For example, when you flag the `@property` as `retain`:

```
objectProperty = anObject; // just accessing locally, no memory management
self.objectProperty = anObject; // [anObject retain] will be called
self.objectProperty = nil; // [anObject release] will be called
```

Comment: ...and don't forget, `myObject.a = 50` is shorthand for `[myObject setA:50]`. The compiler treats both identically. Same goes for `myObject.a` and `[myObject a]`.

Answer (score 2):

In first case you use field, with direct access to it.
In second case you are defining Objective C property, with accessors.

Answer (score 0):

If you define and synthesize a property, then you can also access the value using `int value = self.a; self.a = newValue;`. This also makes the variable accessable to other objects. Without the property, you cannot use the `self.` to get to the variable and there is no automatic way for other objects to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you define and synthesize a property you tell compiler to generate both ivar and accessor methods (-(int)a; and -(void)setA:(int)a_;) for it. Those methods can be called explicitely or implicitely using dot syntax:

```
self.a = num; // [self setA:num] gets called
```